# pass a textbox value to a label inside a grid view on a button click in asp.net 4 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I have 2 asp:panels. One asp:panel contains a textbox and button whose code is as follows

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbGoal" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="222px" Height="26px"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Goal" CssClass="button"  OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />

/* **************************************************************************** 
*                     CODE BEHIND
*
******************************************************************************** */

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I am trying to pass the updated textbox value to a label which is inside a GridView
   // which is inside the second ASP:PANEL  
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is possible. Appreciate it

Comment: you can try using session to pass the value to the label.

Answer (score 1):

First, Identify the row the label will be located.

second, determine if the label can be found `FindControl` method of the grid views selected row.

Once the control has been found, set the value.

the following is only a sample and may not be exact.

```
Label l = (Label)gv.rows[0].FindControl["label"] //again determine the index.

if (l != null)
    l.text = textbox.Text
```

**Alternative:**

Change the dataset that is binding to the Gridview rather than modifying the grids values.  ultimately these values will most likely have to be saved/stored anyway so do it first.