# Trouble with Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a template to have create my gridview. I have have basically created a check box when once select creates a session variable and I then redirect the user to a separate page. The problem is the that the event is not firing off creating the wrapper.

The event:

```
void cmd1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button txtdata = (Button)sender;

        inventoryBLL inv = new inventoryBLL();

        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)txtdata.NamingContainer;

        Label myControl = new Label();

        TableCell tc = gvr.Cells[0];
        // where GridView1 is the id of your GridView and indexOfCell is your index
        foreach (Control c in tc.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                myControl = (Label)c;
            }
        }
        Label myControl1 = new Label();

        List<string> shipmentnames = new List<string>();
        List<string> asinlist = new List<string>();
        List<string> fnskulist = new List<string>();
        List<string> productlist = new List<string>();
        shipmentnames.Add(inv.shipmentname(_ShipmentID));
        asinlist.Add(myControl.Text);
        asinwrapper asin1 = new asinwrapper(asinlist, fnskulist, productlist, 0);
        asinwrapper.CreateSessionWrapper(asin1);
        ShipmentWrapper.CreateSessionWrapper(new ShipmentWrapper(shipmentnames));

    }
```

The code that I create the checkbox:

```
                        CheckBox cmd1 = new CheckBox();                           

                        cmd1.Text = "Change";

                        cmd1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cmd1_Click);

                        cmd1.AutoPostBack = true;

                        container.Controls.Add(cmd1);
```

The code calling the template

```
            bfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplateShipmentItems(ListItemType.Header, "Change", FieldType.Label, ddlShipments.SelectedValue.ToString());

            bfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplateShipmentItems(ListItemType.Item, "Change", FieldType.ButtonAdd, ddlShipments.SelectedValue.ToString());

            grvList.Columns.Add(bfield);

            bfield = new TemplateField();
```

Comment: in which page event you have created the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understood correctly, you have the checkbox embedded in a row of the Gridview, correct?

If so, you have to work with the gridview selected row event, (the checkbox events are now hidden and will not function as expected)
next find the checkbox
determine if the checkbox is checked
redirect the user.

I can get you more precise syntax if you like.

Comment: check out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552826/pass-a-textbox-value-to-a-label-inside-a-grid-view-on-a-button-click-in-asp-net/11552952#11552952) It might provide the details your looking for.